# Cartesian product of a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

So what I want to achieve is the following:
A predicate that when given **2 lists** **returns a list of the Cartesian products of the elements.**
Here is an example.

```
list_mult([1,2,1],[3,4],X).
X = [3,4,6,8,3,4]
```

So far is have this predicate that when given 2 lists of numbers will return the Cartesian product of both lists in a list of lists:

```
product(X,Y,Z):-
    findall([A,B], (member(A,X), member(B,Y), Z).

example: product([1,2],[3,4],X).
X = [[1,3],[1,4],[2,3],[2,4]]
```

So now that i have a list of lists with all the products that i need to do I want to write another predicate that will multiply the elements of a same sub-list between each other:

```
sublistprod([[H|T]|T1],Lfinal):-
    mul(H,T,R),
    L = [],
    add_list(L,Res,Lfinal),
    %sublistprod(.., ..).
```

where "mul" and "add_list" are defined as:

```
mul(A,B,C):-
    C is A * B.

add_list(L,E,R):-
    append(L,[E],R).`
```

What I'm not sure of is how to call the "sublistprod" predicate recursively, by that I mean what do I put in the parameters of the predicate. I have tried calling sublistprod(T1,Lfinal) and that doesn't seem to work.

Any help will be most appreciated.

Comment: just define `p( [A,B], C) :- C is A*B.` and you can `product(X,Y,Z), maplist( p, Z, P).`. also, the standard advice is to define `product(X,Y,Z):-
    findall( A-B, (member(A,X), member(B,Y)) , Z).` instead. (then, of course, define `p( A-B, C) :- C is A*B.`, accordingly).

Comment: Even if you didn't use `maplist` you wouldn't need `add_list`. You can just do a simple iteration: `product_of_pairs([], []).` and `product_of_pairs([[A,B]|Pairs], [Prod|Prods]) :- Prod is A*B, product_of_pairs(Pairs, Prods).`

Comment: @WillNess and "@lurker" (can't @ 2 people..) Thank you both for the quick responses I appreciate it. 
All is working fine now :)

Comment: Without any auxiliary predicate: `?- X = [1,2,1], Y = [3,4], findall(Product, (member(A, X), member(B, Y), Product is A * B), Products).`

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie indeed, mapping a function over structurally combined lists is the same as combining the lists with that function (up to arguments access / repackaging)! ( or in Haskell they'd say `map (uncurry f) .: liftA2 (,) == liftA2 f` ( where `(g .: h) x y = g (h x y)` )) Very nice. maybe you'd post this as an answer.